# i got Connection Refused Error: [Errno 111]

Tags: python, pythonanywhere

i make discord bot. And after run code i have error: Connection Refused Error: [Errno 111]. How i can fix this? I free user. I try write in google more question and i cant find good explanations. Give me good explanations i a beginner in ur hosting.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    return await self._loop.create_connection(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore  # noqa
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1056, in create_connection
    raise exceptions[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1041, in create_connection
    sock = await self._connect_sock(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/base_events.py", line 955, in _connect_sock
    await self.sock_connect(sock, address)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 502, in sock_connect
    return await fut
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 537, in _sock_connect_cb
    raise OSError(err, f'Connect call failed {address}')
```

Comment: Is it free account? Free accounts have limited internet access on PythonAnywhere, limited to whitelisted sites over http(s).

Comment: its Discord, discord in list

Comment: How i can fix this problem?

Comment: I think you're going to need a paid account.  Although Discord itself is whitelisted for free accounts, access to whitelisted sites needs to go via a proxy server.  And unfortunately the normal Discord library can't handle proxies.